# Plot volume planes in python mayavi with no voxel interpolation

Tags: python, plot, volume, mayavi

I'm using `mayavi.mlab` to plot cut planes through a volume in python.

The rendering is always interpolated. Is there a way to plot these planes without interpolation so that the pixels / voxels are visible?

**Example code showing cut planes through a 20x20x20 voxel volume.**

```py
"""
Testing  scalar_cut_plane
"""
import numpy as np
import mayavi.mlab as mlab

# creating volume that increases in value
img3d = np.arange(20)
img3d = np.expand_dims(img3d, axis=1)
img3d = np.expand_dims(img3d, axis=2)
img3d = np.tile(img3d, (1, 20, 20))

fig = mlab.figure()
src = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(img3d)

# Plotting two cut planes
cp2 = mlab.pipeline.scalar_cut_plane(src, plane_orientation='y_axes')
cp2.implicit_plane.widget.enabled = False
cp3 = mlab.pipeline.scalar_cut_plane(src, plane_orientation='z_axes')
cp3.implicit_plane.widget.enabled = False
mlab.view(azimuth=50, elevation=None)
mlab.outline()
mlab.show()
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best workaround that I could find to this problem was to use scipy interpolation to enlarge the volume without interpolation.

```py
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import zoom
img3d2 = zoom(img3d, 4, order=0)
```

[image]

The voxel size is now visible

Answer (score 2):

I am a very casual user of mayavi, so by no means an expert, but I did manage to hack something together without upscaling. For that I used `image_plane_widget` instead of `scalar_cut_plane`, not entirely sure of the difference.

```
import numpy as np
import mayavi.mlab as mlab

# creating volume that increases in value
img3d = np.arange(20)
img3d = np.expand_dims(img3d, axis=1)
img3d = np.expand_dims(img3d, axis=2)
img3d = np.tile(img3d, (1, 20, 20))

fig = mlab.figure()
src = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(img3d)

# Plotting two cut planes
cp2 = mlab.pipeline.image_plane_widget(src, plane_orientation='y_axes')
cp3 = mlab.pipeline.image_plane_widget(src, plane_orientation='z_axes')

for p in [cp2, cp3]:
    p.ipw.texture_interpolate = "off"
    p.ipw.set_input_data(p.ipw._get_input())

mlab.view(azimuth=50, elevation=None)
mlab.outline()
mlab.show()
```

[image: mayavi image_plane_widget texture interpolation]

A mere `texture_interpolate = "off"` does not work, as mentioned in the vtk docs:

> Set before setting the vtkImageData input. Default is On.

http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImagePlaneWidget.html

Comment: Useful! I was modifying the constructor to do this since this needs to be done before image loading. 

Another thing I found useful for me is to also set the reslice interpolate. So just add:
    `p.ipw.reslice_interpolate = "nearest_neighbour";`

to the for loop.